# Azure AD implementation in ASP.NET SPA

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

i have ASP.NET (4.7) Single Page Application with forms authentication. SPA is developed using Typescript and API. now client would like to migrate to Azure Authentication. i have not used typescript and SPA. so its very difficult for me to implement the Authentication and Authorization.

can anyone share steps to implement the authentication process for SPA with typescript.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an older blog post that could get you familiar with it: https://jpvelasco.com/angularjs-single-page-app-with-azure-ad-and-typescript/